# Find new values in new table

Tags: sql-server

I Have Table NEW:

```
Customer   Date      Id
1          201401     9
1          201401     1
1          201402     2
2          201404     3
2          201404     4
3          201406     5
4          201408     6
```

And table OLD:

```
Customer   Date      Id
1          201401     1
1          201402     2
2          201404     3
2          201404     4
3          201406     5
4          201408     6
```

Table NEW has all values from table OLD plus some new ones that are not in table OLD.

I need to find Customer that has same Key (column Customer) and same Date (Date) in both tables (OLD and NEW) and different ID in those tables.

So the `SELECT` should return in this case only

```
1          201401     9
```

I tried simple join :

```
SELECT *
FROM NEW n 
LEFT JOIN OLD o ON n.ID = o.ID
WHERE n.Date = o.Date 
AND n.ID <> o.ID
```

but its obviously wrong because of the condition for the join. But I can't join it on Customer so how can i do it some other way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM NEW n 
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 FROM Old o
   WHERE n.Customer = o.Customer AND  n.Date = o.Date
   AND   n.ID <> o.ID
)
AND NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 FROM Old o
   WHERE n.Customer = o.Customer AND  n.Date = o.Date
   AND   n.ID = o.ID
)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2175/9/0)